# Squid bypass site don't work (as expected)

Tags: squid

Here is my squid.conf

```
http_access allow localhost
acl whoer dstdomain .whoer.net
http_access allow whoer
never_direct allow whoer
# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
always_direct allow all
http_access allow all
```

I don't know how to properly use always_direct to connect to proxy only if I am on whoer.net site. On all other sites, I want to connect through my origin IP.

If I disable `http_access allow all` it's don't work. I try to move `always_direct allow all` upper and down - no result.

Can you give advise me how to fix it? Thx